# Detect if process memory being manipulated?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I was wondering how one could monitor the process memory of another application and see if it is being manipulated by a third party. Such as when ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory are called on a specific process. For example, nProtect GameGuard can detect when a games process memory is being manipulated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to detect when OpenProcess, ReadProcessMemory, WriteProcessMemory are being called on my application. I would like to monitor this via a separate program though.

Comment: Possibly a system wide hook of sort. You'd inject into every process, and monitor their calls to the functions, and if the process id matches yours, you act according?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer could be very lenghthy so here are a few short tips for you.

First, you need some system-wide hooks to these functions, and their lower-level building blocks (Zw..., Nt..., and even system call). This should be done by a kernel driver.

Second, you need a way to install this driver, and remove it at will. This can be done by a service.

Third, you need a way to communicate between the kernel driver, and the game. During its initialization stage, the game will install the driver, and tell it which process ID the game is running. The driver will then block all access to that particular process from other processes.

Fourth, you need to maintain a white list. Applications such as antivirus do need to peek and poke at your game. Your kernel driver must allow these examination to pass. This is where nProtect and similar technologies fail. They just keep conflicting with other softwares.

Fifth, maybe it's time to think of other ways to protect your game. The paper "Tamper Resistant Software: An Implementation" by David Aucsmith is worth reading.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with your fifth suggestion. I was hoping it wouldn't have to be so invasive.

Comment: Sorry for posting on an old thread, but this is also a good read. Although it takes a slightly different approach, it introduces a lot of good methods to detect and offset memory manipulation, including hashing/redundancy.
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/venkie/jakubowski09tts.pdf